# Louis Aslett AWS Rstudio AMI doesn't link to Dropbox

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, rstudio, dropbox, amazon-ami

I am having trouble with some instances not linking to dropbox. I get a permanent "Launching Dropbox client, please wait ..." with no url link ever showing up. I cant figure out the instance pattern. Most recently it failed with a spot instance of r4.8xlarge ami-82ccade2. any ideas?

Comment: still not sure what the issue is but I manages to get around it by creating an image of a working instance and then using it when launching a new instance.  Dropbox works as expected.